# 'id' expected a number but got AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django

Помогите разобраться в ошибке:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got
<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000022009F7BF60>
```

Вот вью:

```
from api import filters, pagination, permissions
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import mixins, status, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .file import send_file
from .models import Favorite, Ingredient, Recipe, ShoppingList, Tag
from .serializers import (CreateRecipeSerializer, FavouriteSerializer,
                          IngredientSerializer, ReadyRecipeSerializer,
                          ShoppingListSerializer, TagSerializer)


class TagsViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    pagination_class = None


class IngredientsViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = filters.IngredientFilter
    pagination_class = None


class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = filters.RecipeFilter
    pagination_class = pagination.CustomPageNumberPaginator

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return (
            ReadyRecipeSerializer if self.request.method == 'GET' else
            CreateRecipeSerializer
        )

    @staticmethod
    def delete_method(request, pk, model):
        get_object_or_404(
            model,
            user=request.user,
            recipe=get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=pk)
        ).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    @staticmethod
    def post_method(request, pk, serializer):
        data = {'user': request.user.id, 'recipe': pk}
        serializer = serializer(
            data=data, context={'request': request}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=['POST', ],
        permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthorOrAdmin]
    )
    def favorite(self, request, pk):
        return self.post_method(
            request=request, pk=pk, serializer=FavouriteSerializer
        )

    @favorite.mapping.delete
    def delete_favorite(self, request, pk):
        return self.delete_method(request=request, pk=pk, model=Favorite)

    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=['POST', ],
        permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthorOrAdmin]
    )
    def shopping_cart(self, request, pk):
        return self.post_method(
            request=request, pk=pk, serializer=ShoppingListSerializer
        )

    @shopping_cart.mapping.delete
    def delete_shopping_cart(self, request, pk):
        get_object_or_404(
            ShoppingList,
            user=request.user,
            recipe=get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=pk)
        ).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ])
    def download_shopping_cart(self, request):
        return send_file(
            request, f'Список покупок: {request.user}.txt'
        )
```

Вот модели:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core import validators
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Тег',
        unique=True,
        max_length=50,
    )
    color = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Цвет тега',
        unique=True,
        max_length=50,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name='Ссылка на тег',
        unique=True,
        max_length=150,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Тег'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Теги'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        verbose_name='Название ингредиента'
    )
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        verbose_name='Мера измерения'
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Ингредиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ингредиенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='recipes',
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, verbose_name='Название'
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipes/',
        verbose_name='Изображение',
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000, verbose_name='Описание рецепта'
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        through='IngredientForRecipe',
        verbose_name='Ингредиенты',
    )
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=(
            validators.MinValueValidator(
                1, message='Ошибка. Время не может быть меньше 1.'),
            validators.MaxValueValidator(
                6000, message='Ошибка. Недопустимое значение времени')
        ),
        verbose_name='Время приготовления'
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag,
        verbose_name='Теги',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class IngredientForRecipe(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        Ingredient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ingredients_amounts',
    )
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ingredients_amounts',
    )
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=(
            validators.MinValueValidator(
                1, message='Ошибка. Ингредиентов не может быть меньше 1.'),
            validators.MaxValueValidator(
                10000, message='Ошибка. Ингредиентов слишком много.')
        ),
        verbose_name='Количество ингредиентов',
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['recipe', 'ingredient'],
                name='unique_recipe_ingredient',
            )
        ]
        verbose_name = 'Ингредиенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.ingredient}: {self.recipe}'


class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='favorite',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        related_name='is_favorited',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)
        verbose_name = 'Избранное'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Избранное'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'recipe'],
                name='unique_favorite',
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.recipe}: {self.user}'


class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='purchase',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Покупка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Покупки'
        ordering = ('-id',)
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'recipe'],
                name='unique_shopping_cart'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.recipe}: {self.user}'
```

Вот сериализатор:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from users.serializers import CustomUserSerializer

from .models import (Favorite, Ingredient, IngredientForRecipe, Recipe,
                     ShoppingList, Tag)

User = get_user_model()


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'color', 'slug')


class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit')


class RecipeIngredientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.name')
    measurement_unit = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='ingredient.measurement_unit'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientForRecipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit', 'amount')


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'cooking_time')


class ReadyRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    ingredients = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_in_shopping_cart = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'id', 'tags', 'author',
            'ingredients', 'name', 'image',
            'text', 'image', 'cooking_time',
            'is_favorited', 'is_in_shopping_cart'
        )

    def get_ingredients(self, obj):
        return RecipeIngredientsSerializer(
            IngredientForRecipe.objects.filter(recipe=obj), many=True
        ).data

    def get_is_favorited(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if not request or request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        return Favorite.objects.filter(recipe=obj, user=request.user).exists()

    def get_is_in_shopping_cart(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if not request or request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        return ShoppingList.objects.filter(
            recipe=obj,
            user=request.user
        ).exists()


class FavouriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Recipe.objects.all())
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = ('user', 'recipe')

    def validate(self, data):
        user = data['user']
        recipe_id = data['recipe'].id
        if Favorite.objects.filter(user=user, recipe__id=recipe_id).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Рецепт уже добавлен в избранное!')
        return data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return ReadyRecipeSerializer(
            instance.recipe,
            context={
                'request': self.context.get('request')
            }
        ).data


class ShoppingListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipe = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Recipe.objects.all())
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingList
        fields = ('user', 'recipe')

    def validate(self, data):
        user = data['user']
        recipe_id = data['recipe'].id
        if ShoppingList.objects.filter(user=user,
                                       recipe__id=recipe_id).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Рецепт уже добавлен в список покупок')
        return data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return ReadyRecipeSerializer(
            instance.recipe,
            context={
                'request': self.context.get('request')
            }
        ).data


class CreateIngredientsForRecipeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.all())
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientForRecipe
        fields = ('id', 'amount')


class CreateRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField()
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True
    )
    ingredients = CreateIngredientsForRecipeSerializers(many=True)
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True
    )
    cooking_time = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=(MinValueValidator(1, 'Время не может быть меньше 1'),)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'id', 'author', 'ingredients',
            'tags', 'image', 'name',
            'text', 'cooking_time')

    @staticmethod
    def create_ingredients(ingredients, recipe):
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            IngredientForRecipe.objects.create(
                recipe=recipe,
                ingredient=ingredient['id'],
                amount=ingredient['amount']
            )

    @staticmethod
    def create_tags(tags, recipe):
        for tag in tags:
            recipe.tags.add(tag)

    def validate(self, data):
        ingredients = self.initial_data.get('ingredients')
        ingredients_list = []
        tags = self.initial_data.get('tags')
        tags_list = []
        if not ingredients:
            raise ValidationError('Не выбраны ингредиенты')
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            if int(ingredient['amount']) <= 0:
                raise ValidationError(
                    f'{ingredient} указано не допустимое кол-во ингредиентов :'
                    f'{ingredient["amount"]}'
                )
            if ingredient['id'] in ingredients_list:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'Ингредиенты не должны повторяться'
                )
            ingredients_list.append(ingredient['id'])
        for tag in tags:
            if tag in tags_list:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'Теги не должны повторяться'
                )
            tags_list.append(tag)
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author = self.context.get('request').user
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(author=author, **validated_data)
        self.create_tags(tags, recipe)
        self.create_ingredients(ingredients, recipe)
        return recipe

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.tags.clear()
        IngredientForRecipe.objects.filter(recipe=instance).all().delete()
        self.create_tags(validated_data.pop('tags'), instance)
        self.create_ingredients(validated_data.pop('ingredients'), instance)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return ReadyRecipeSerializer(
            instance,
            context={
                'request': self.context.get('request')
            }
        ).data
```

Если что, могу скинуть ссылку на репозиторий в гитхабе.
Ошибка возникает при GET запросе:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipes/?page=1&limit=6&is_favorited=1
```

Comment: Вы где то передаете пользователя, но нет проверки что он авторизован